# If/else statement with change image function not working for multiple images

Tags: javascript, image, function, if-statement

I am very new to javascript and am in need of some help. My goal is to have 3 before photos that you click on to reveal the after photo (dog grooming website). With only one before/after photo the code works fine but with all 3 only the last one functions properly. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? If/else statements are still very new for me and not sure if I am using them properly.

```
<p>Click the dog to <br>show their transformation.</p>

<img id="dog1" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog1before.PNG" width="300" >
<br>
<img id="dog2" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog2before.PNG" width="300" >
<br>
<img id="dog3" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog3before.PNG" width="300" >

<script>
//dog1 before and after
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("dog1");
  if (image.src.match("dog1after")) {
    image.src = "images/dog1before.PNG";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/dog1after.PNG";
  }
}

//dog2 before and after
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("dog2");
  if (image.src.match("dog2after")) {
    image.src = "images/dog2before.PNG";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/dog2after.PNG";
  }
}    

//dog3 before and after
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("dog3");
  if (image.src.match("dog3after")) {
    image.src = "images/dog3before.PNG";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/dog3after.PNG";
  }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: You have a single function named `changeImage` that you re-define three times. Last one wins.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick callback function names are the same, try changing them to changeImageA, changeImageB and changeImageC or something.

Once you have that it would be better to use a single function, pass in an argument and do a switch statement or if/else to change the image depending which one was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use one function for all images:

```
<p>Click the dog to <br>show their transformation.</p>

<img id="dog1" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog1before.PNG" width="300" >
<br>
<img id="dog2" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog2before.PNG" width="300" >
<br>
<img id="dog3" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/dog3before.PNG" width="300" >

<script>
function changeImage(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  if (image.src.match("after")) {
    image.src = "images/" + event.target.id + "before.PNG";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/" + event.target.id + "after.PNG";
  }
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using the dataset:

```
<script>
function changeImage(elm) {
    var after = elm.dataset.after;
    var src = elm.getAttribute('src');

    if (after && src !== after) {
        elm.setAttribute('src', after);
    }
}
</script>

<img src='images/dog1before.PNG' data-after='images/dog1after.PNG' onclick='changeImage(this);' />

<img src='images/dog2before.PNG' data-after='images/dog2after.PNG' onclick='changeImage(this);' />

<img src='images/dog3before.PNG' data-after='images/dog3after.PNG' onclick='changeImage(this);' />
```